# Is $\Vert \max(0, M-x)\Vert^2$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives

I think $\max(0, M-x)^2$ is differentiable everywhere, but what if $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, can we prove that $f(x) = \Vert \max(0, M-x)\Vert^2, x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable? $M \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a constant, when

$$x \in \mathbb{R}^n,  \max(0, M-x) = \begin{bmatrix}\max(0, M_1 - x_1) \\ \vdots \\ \max(0, M_n - x_n)\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Comment: What is $\max(0, M-x)$? The component-wise maximum?

Comment: @MartinR it’s componentwise maximum.

Comment: So $\Vert \max(0, M-x)\Vert^2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \max(0, M_i - x_i)^2$ is the sum of differentiable functions.

Comment: @MartinR yes, exactly.

Comment: Martin is saying a sum of $n$ differentiable functions is itself a differentiable function.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen But that’s for the same variable, here we know $f_i(x_i)$ is differentiable, but can we say $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x_i)$ is differentiable for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You consider those $n$ functions to be all functions of the full $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. With other words, all $n$ terms can be seen as functions of all the variables $x_1,\ldots,x_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that
$$
 \Bbb R \ni t \mapsto \max(0, M-t)^2
$$
is differentiable. It follows that
$$
 \Bbb R^n \ni x \mapsto f(x) = \Vert \max(0, M-x)\Vert^2
 = \sum_{j=1}^n \max(0, M_i - \pi_i(x))^2
$$
is differentiable as well, because:

- Each projection: $\pi_i : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R, \pi_i(x) = x_i$ is differentiable (because it is a linear mapping), and
- the sum of differentiable functions is differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

The function $g(x) = \lVert x \rVert^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$ is differentiable. If $h(x):=max(0,M-x)$ is also differentiable, then by the chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f\bigl(h(x)\bigr) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\bigl(g(x)\bigr)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_i}(x).$$
Hence, since both $f$ and $h$ are differentiable over $\mathbb R^n$, $f\circ h$ is also differentiable. But that is assuming $max(0, M-x)$ is differentiable.

Comment: actually,$ \max(0, M-x)$ is not differentiable everywhere.